# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in (author-links.php on line 1)

Tags: php

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in /home/pradeepnirmal/dialtoneeds.com/wp-content/plugins/seo-ultimate/modules/author-links/author-links.php on line 1

```
            if (class_exists('SU_Module')) {

            define('SU_AUTHORLINKS_MODE_OFF', 0);
            define('SU_AUTHORLINKS_MODE_SINGLEAUTHOR', 1);
            define('SU_AUTHORLINKS_MODE_MULTIAUTHOR', 2);

            class SU_AuthorLinks extends SU_Module {

                function get_module_title() { return __('Author Highlighter', 'seo-ultimate'); }

                function get_parent_module() { return 'misc'; }
                function get_settings_key() { return 'author-links'; }



                }

            }

            }
            ?>
```

I looked at the line before the syntax, but I couldn't find what is wrong... Does someone know it?

Comment: Please paste all of the code :)

Comment: Are you missing `<?php` ? I am not sure if that would cause the error you are seeing

Answer (score 0):

```
        if (class_exists('SU_Module')) {

            define('SU_AUTHORLINKS_MODE_OFF', 0);
            define('SU_AUTHORLINKS_MODE_SINGLEAUTHOR', 1);
            define('SU_AUTHORLINKS_MODE_MULTIAUTHOR', 2);

            class SU_AuthorLinks extends SU_Module {

                function get_module_title() { return __('Author Highlighter', 'seo-ultimate'); }

                function get_parent_module() { return 'misc'; }
                function get_settings_key() { return 'author-links'; }             

            }

        }
```

You had one extra `}`.